# How to adjust y-axis title position of UpSet plot in R?

Tags: r, upsetr

I can't figure out how to adjust the position of the y-axis title in this UpSet plot.
It is moved far over to the left due to the length of the variable names.  I have created a replicable example below:

```
library(UpSetR)
library(dplyr)

movies <- read.csv( system.file("extdata", "movies.csv", package = "UpSetR"), header=TRUE, sep=";" )


movies_upd <- movies %>%
    dplyr::select(
        # make a variable with a long name to replicate problem
        moviechoiceAdventurefilm = Adventure,
        Children,
        Action
    ) %>% 
    as.data.frame()

upset(movies_upd)
```

[image: upset plot]

How can I move the Y-axis title closer to the plot on the right?